# Regex Match multiple lines and provide condition for end of match

Tags: regex, regex-group

So I have this text that I am trying to parse with Regex:

```
Name: Test Data 1
Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec feugiat nulla id nisi venenatis blandit.
 Donec blandit egestas orci, at tristique dui vehicula in. Maecenas fringilla fringilla enim, in pulvinar ex gravida
 in. Nam cursus facilisis ante, sed tristique nisl sagittis sed. In auctor felis id neque suscipit ullamcorper. Nunc
 faucibus elit sed metus vestibulum, ullamcorper pulvinar nisi auctor. Praesent sodales orci mauris, eget dapibus
 mauris sodales in. Ut iaculis, ante vitae ullamcorper semper, metus tortor auctor purus, eu convallis nulla lacus
 in tellus. Phasellus feugiat tempus neque, in fringilla nisi scelerisque sed. Donec elementum diam nec mattis dignissim.
```

I am trying to parse it to load it into a database.

With this expression, I am trying to get a match on the "Name" and "Description" parameters but also trying to get a match on the parameter value as well (which can sometimes be multi-line).

```
(.*):\s(.*)
```

I have been searching for a while now and I cannot seem to be able to make it match the whole paragraph but stop when it hits a blank line.

I would like the result to be as follows:

- 1st Match

  - Group 1: Name
  - Group 2: Test Data 1
- 2nd Match

  - Group 1: Description
  - Group 2: Description value with multi-line

https://regex101.com/r/mG2ms9/3

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using this in? Can the text vary in spacing, new lines, or anything else? Also, do you need anything to be captured or just matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(.*?):\s([\s\S]*?)(?=\n(?:\n|\w|$))
```

[Here it is on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/mG2ms9/5)

`[\s\S]` matches any character, even a new line (whereas '.' does not, by default).

Then we're matching as few characters as possible (`*?`) up until the point where the next line is either blank (`\n`), starts with a word character (`\w`), or is the end of the string (`$`).

We can get away with the `\w` option since all of the new lines in the description parameter are followed by a space. If this isn't always the case, you could replace `\w` with something like `.*:` to check instead if the next line contains ':' and stop if so.

Note that I disabled multi-line mode; it's not suitable here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!